# Does a Python Stoppable Thread needs to be Daemonized or be .join()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, ubuntu, python-multithreading

When using a class `Pup` for creating stoppable threads that are meant to be running in the background until `.stop()` is called:

1. What happens when `pup.join()` is not called after `pup.stop()`? Will the following result in a leak:

   ```
   pup = Pup()
   pup.start()
   time.sleep(5)
   pup.stop()

   pup2 = Pup()
   pup2.start()
   time.sleep(5)
   pup2.stop()

   pup3 = Pup()
   pup3.start()
   time.sleep(5)
   pup3.stop()
   ```
2. Must `pup` be a daemonized thread since we are running it in the background?

Main code below is borrowed from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382332/example-usages-of-the-stoppablethread-subclass-of-pythons-threading-thread/40382407#40382407)

```
import time
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stopper = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stopper.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stopper.isSet()


class Pup(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, i, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Pup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.i = i

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.stopped():
                return
            print("Hello, world!", i)
            time.sleep(1)

for i in range(100):
    pup = Pup(i)
    pup.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    pup.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StoppableThread` should be `join`ed.

Because it is just a thin wrapper about `threading.Thread` giving you a possibility of setting and checking flag `stopper`.

In this case, there must be a code that regularly checks this flag. The amount of delay between checks depends on the user of the class.
And given the fact that it is assumed that the thread should be correctly stopped, you must use `join`. Because if you make the thread as `daemon` and try to stop it before the application finishing:

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

1. A leak is possible only if your code is responsible for checking the `stopper` flag and subsequent exiting from the thread does not work correctly. Otherwise, there is no leaks, because the app, even `join` is not called, will wait for the completion of all non-daemon threads. But using `join` will give more control over  the program flow.
2. Taking all of the above into consideration, i think that making `StoppableThread` as `daemon` is bad idea.